# Abort HTTP PUT request when server sends an error with HttpClient-4

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using httpclient-4 to send the content of a stream (a huge file in this case) to my Tomcat's upload servlet using the following code:

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpPut(destination);
InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(inputStream, contentLength);
((HttpPut)httpRequest).setEntity(entity);
httpClient.execute(httpRequest,handler);
```

It worked fine. I later added an authentication mechanism to prevent unauthorized user to upload files. If someone tries to upload without being authenticated the servlet directly responds with an

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN)
```

without even processing the request's InputStream.

The problem I am facing is that despite the fact that the request is rejected on the server side, my client keeps sending the whole content of the InputStream resulting in a completely useless network usage.

I have looked inside the documentation of the httpclient but unfortunately didn't find anything about this point. I have also looked on the tomcat's side to see if it's possible to abort a request but [it doesn't seem possible](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-dev/200803.mbox/%3C47DD0A9A.1080502@knowleses.org%3E).

Is there a way to cancel the upload of the stream in this situation?

Any insights will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157132/aborting-upload-from-a-servlet) is example using apache common-file-update.

Comment: @Santosh Thanks for the link but I can't use it as I'm not working with files but directly with the stream. Indeed, if user is authorized to do so, the content of the stream is split in blocks and directly redirected to a Voldemort back-end for storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper solution to this problem would be turning on the so called 'expect: continue' handshake on the client side. Newer releases of Apache HttpClient 4.x have it disabled per default.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. I still have some Tomcat issues to make it handle it correctly but it shouldn't be a big deal to fix. Thanks for your help here and on the mailing list!

Answer (score 1):

You can close the InputStream on the server side and it will stop the transfer.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I have added `request.getInputStream().close();` on the server side and the whole content of the file is still sent. Call starts at 12:00:32,813, server sends error and closes stream at 12:00:32:936, but the response handler only executes at 12:00:44:883. Network usage shows that file is still being sent. I have tried to close the stream after/before setting the error response headers but it's always the same.