# Limiting upload size on Server side in Java

Tags: java, file-upload, grails-2.0, filesize

I have a form that has an upload input on it. Use can upload files up to 10MB, this limit is set on the client side as a JS function. In case someone intentionally disable the JavaScript on their browser and try to upload huge files to the server, what back-end options do I have to intercept this ? Is reading the multi-part header file size a reliable approach ? Or should I use limited buffer file/input reader that drop the stream if it exceeds certain number of bytes ? I want something reliable to back my JS function on the server side. My back-end is Grails, so I can use Java/Groovy to implement this, also I have access to Spring Framework.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157132/aborting-upload-from-a-servlet-to-limit-file-size might be helpful

Comment: Your concern is justified, request headers can be deceitful (for reference reading)